# file,excel concept in C# console application

Tags: c#, excel

my txt file containt

```
empno name  salary
101   lekha  20000
102   hema   30000
```

i want to change the salary of 102-hema , is this possible to change? .how to change.

again i want  to store,retrieve,update data into excel using C# console application

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text; 

namespace Excelcalling1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string F1Name = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\origin\\Desktop\\New Folder\\Book1.xls";
            string CnStr = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + ("Data Source="    
            + ( F1Name + (";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\""))));

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", CnStr);                         
            Console.WriteLine("File Accessed!!!!");                                                 

            try
            { 
                DA.Fill(ds, "srlno");
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["srlno"].Rows)
                {                        
                    Console.WriteLine(dr["A"] + "\t" + dr["B"] + "\t" + dr["C"]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can import that into excel and query this information. Or there is a txt odbc driver you can use that look @ http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AccessTextDb12052005071306AM/AccessTextDb.aspx